# Who is Quinten on Supergirl?

Tags: character, arrowverse, supergirl

Actor Jonathan Bennett announced on Instagram that he would be playing the role of Quinten (A government attaché) on Supergirl. Who is Quinten? Is he an important character in season 4?

[image: Instagram Snapshot]

So far he appeared on one episode where he has a change of heart and helps aliens.

Comment: I don't watch *Supergirl* but isn't this Future work?

Comment: @Taladris What do you mean? I just thought Quinten might be a character from the comics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Who is Quinten on Supergirl?**

> Per The CW, Bennett’s character Quentin is a “wide-eyed government attaché who is grateful when Supergirl saves his life. However, when he shows his true colors by attending an anti-alien rally, Supergirl aims to prove to Quentin that not all aliens are bad.” - [tvline](https://tvline.com/2019/01/10/supergirl-spoilers-jonathan-bennett-cast-season-4-episode-14/)

He is credited for one episode only and from DC comics there is no one named Quinten with any prominent appearance.

Also, he is being called as "Guest Star" not a regular.